# Gurobi - Python: is there a way to express "OR" in a constraint?

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, python, constraint, gurobi

I'm new to Gurobi in Python and I am wondering if there is way to express/code "or" in the following constraint, where $x_i$  are binary variables:

$x_i-x_i*x_{i-1} =0$

OR

$x_i*x_{i+1} =1.$

**Question:**

Is there a way to express "Or" between the above two constraints?

**My Approch:**

I tried the following
model.addConstr((x[i]-x[i]*x[i-1]) * (x[i]*x[i+1] -1 )==0)
however this leads to an error:

> gurobipy.GurobiError: Invalid argument to QuadExpr multiplication

I think that `addConstr` can take at max three multiplications.

Comment: 1) Take a look at these two links from gurobi: [or_ function](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_or_.html) and [indicator constraints](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_agc_indicator.html). 
2) There are other questions on this site about formulating "OR" constraints. Make sure to search for it

Comment: @EhsanK  In fact, or_function doesn't work in this case, indicator constraints  could work, but I do not see how. I already searched for the other questions about "OR" constraints, didn't find something suitable.

Comment: Hi @M.Badaoui May you could expand a bit on what you want to achieve. Maybe there is a better way to formulate the logic you want to enforce? The first constraint says that "if $x_i=1$ then $x_{i-1}$ must equal 1 as well" the second say "both $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ must be one". Note that you can formulate both of these constraints linearly: $x_i\leq x_{i-1}$ and $x_i+x_{i+1}=2$

Comment: Boolean type constraints are more familiar to Constraint Programming type of problems. It is almost always possible to write them in MIP with a little more difficulty. OR-Tools has boolean operators for its CP-SAT module https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/sat/python/cp_model#addboolor  Btw, it seems what you are trying is nonlinear, which may be another problem depending on the solver type.

Comment: Hi @Sune thanks for your comment! it is difficult to explain the objective of this constraint here, I was looking for something similar to CPLEX in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710025/how-to-implement-logical-or-constraint-in-cplex-python   Seems it is not the case for gurobi.

Comment: @berkorbay Thanks for your comment! I was hopping to simpler way to express "OR" in constraint (like CPLEX in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710025/how-to-implement-logical-or-constraint-in-cplex-python) Seems that there is no direct solution for gurobi.

Comment: @M.Badaoui I might have missed something but I think I have an answer for you for your specific case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $x_i$'s are binary:
$$
\begin{align*}
&(x_i(1 - x_{i-1}) = 0) \vee (x_ix_{i+1}=1)\\
\Leftrightarrow&(\neg x_i \vee x_{i-1})\vee(x_i \wedge x_{i+1})\\
\Leftrightarrow&\neg x_i \vee x_{i-1}\vee(x_i \wedge x_{i+1})\\
\Leftrightarrow&(\neg x_i \vee x_{i-1}\vee x_i) \wedge (\neg x_i \vee x_{i-1}\vee x_{i+1})\\
\Leftrightarrow& 1 \wedge (\neg x_i \vee x_{i-1} \vee x_{i+1})\\
\Leftrightarrow& \neg x_i \vee x_{i-1} \vee x_{i+1}\\
\Leftrightarrow& (1-x_i) + x_{i-1} + x_{i+1} \geq 1\\
\Leftrightarrow& x_{i-1} - x_i + x_{i+1} \geq 0
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you! Using the last inequality we can formulate the constraint in gurobi. I was hopping for something similar to CPLEX in this question (to express OR constraint directly): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710025/how-to-implement-logical-or-constraint-in-cplex-python Seems that there no direct way in Gurobi like Cplex.

Comment: See `addGenConstrOr` and `addGenConstrIndicator` @M.Badaoui

Answer (score 4):

Edit: This is actually the "English" version of @xd y's accepted answer.

In your specific case I think adding just $x_{i+1} \ge x_i-x_{i-1}$ works. Let's enumerate

If $x_i = 0$ then your OR constraint is satisfied since LHS will be 0 for both constraints. Other variables are free.

If $x_i = 1$ and $x_{i+1} = 1$ then the second constraint is satisfied. $x_{i-1}$ is free.

If $x_i = 1$ and $x_{i+1} = 0$ then $x_{i-1}$ should be 1.

So if you add $x_{i+1} \ge x_i-x_{i-1}$, you ensure that if $x_{i} = 1$ and $x_{i-1} = 0$ you will get $x_{i+1} = 1$. Otherwise, $x_{i+1}$ is free.

Answer (score 1):

$x_i*(1-x_{i-1} = 0\ or \ x_i*x_{i+1}=1$ implies
Cons(1): $x_i*(1-x_{i-1}) >=0$;
Cons(2): $x_i*x_{i+1} <=1$;
Cons(3): $x_i*(1-x_{i-1} + x_{i+1}) =1$
So if you are looking for 0 or 1 for cons(1) & cons(2) & not either way then constraints are:
$x_i = 1$
$x_{i+1} >= x_{i-1}$